# How to install package from source in groovy?

Tags: ros, catkin, package, ros-groovy, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm just starting out with ROS, and I'm trying to install some ROS packages, but there is no .deb file available, so I cant use apt-get. For example, package [tf2_web_republisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2_web_republisher). How do I go about installing from source? I've read posts such as:

http://answers.ros.org/question/61693/individual-package-install/

http://answers.ros.org/question/36784/how-to-install-a-stack-and-package-manually-in-fuerte/

but they use the command rosws. I believe this uses rosbuild. Since I'm using groovy, I'd like to build it using catkin. Can someone kindly guide me how to install packages from source on groovy using catkin?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70321/how-to-install-package-from-source-in-groovy?/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure this package has been catkinized ? If it has not, you'd better just use rosbuild.

If it has been catkinized, you can just download it in your catkin workspace and do a catkin_make. This should work.

If you want it to be in a specific directory, you can create a new workspace where you place this package, and use catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-07-31**:
Thanks for your quick answer Lucile! After performing catkin_make, do I have to do catkin_make install?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-31**:
If you use the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, I think you will need to, but I am not sure. In the source installation tutorial I used (http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Installation) they used make install in build folder.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-07-31**:
I went ahead and did catkin_make install anyway. Thanks!